# NoReverseMatch Reverse for '' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '' not found

Tags: django, django-urls

I have this in a django view:

`edit_url = reverse('ventas:clientes_edit',kwargs={'id':str(self.object.id)})`

And this in urls.py:

`url(r'^clientes/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$',forms.ClienteUpdateView.as_view(), name="clientes_edit"),`

When I create a new customer via ajax I need to return a reverse url with the id in a JSON data to put in a series of actions buttons for edit, delete... but always I get this error and I don't know how to accomplish it, this the complete error:

`NoReverseMatch at /ventas/clientes/add/
Reverse for 'clientes_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': '38'}' not found.`

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The Django version is 1.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The kwargs should pass the pk not id to match the url

```
edit_url = reverse('ventas:clientes_edit',kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})
```

also your url expects an int pk not string.